# Javascript Variable is Undefined (cookie data)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a HTML webpage with some JS. JS is suppose to send username and password data to my server, but the data (JSON format) is showing up as undefined. For some reason the var username and password are "undefined", but the whole POST shows up in JSON format (which is what I want).

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var messageType = "3";
    var cookie_name = "username"; 
    var cookie_name2 = "password";
    var YouWrote = getName(cookie_name);
    var YouWrote2 = getName2(cookie_name2);
    var userName = YouWrote;
    var password = YouWrote2;
    auth(messageType, userName, password);
});


$.ajaxSetup({
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
});


function auth(messageType, userName, password) {
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        //SEND TO SERVER URL
        url: "######",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: '{"messageType": "' + messageType + '", "userName": "' + userName + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',

        error: function (xhr, error) {
           alert('Error!');
        },

        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#response').html(data.details + '\nHello ' + data.clientInfo.firstName + ' ' + data.clientInfo.lastName + '. \nBalance:' + data.clientInfo.balance);
        }
    })
}


function getName(cookie_name) {
    if(document.cookie)
    {
    index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name);
    if (index != -1)
    {
    namestart = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
    nameend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
    if (nameend == -1) {nameend = document.cookie.length;}
    YouWrote = document.cookie.substring(namestart, nameend);
    return YouWrote;
}}}

function getName2(cookie_name2) {
    if(document.cookie)
    {
    index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name2);
    if (index != -1)
    {

    namestart = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
    nameend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
    if (nameend == -1) {nameend = document.cookie.length;}
    YouWrote2 = document.cookie.substring(namestart, nameend);
    return YouWrote2;
}}}
```

Cookie values are saved properly. There is something in them. In:

```
data: '{"messageType": "' + messageType + '", "userName": "' + userName + '", "password" : "' + password + '"}',
```

messageType shows up as "3", but userName and password are "undefined". Is this a case of not defining global variables?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: **Don't save password in a cookie**

Comment: You have the same method with 2 different names.... `getName` & `getName2` are the same exception of the parameter name

Comment: I know this is not the standard, but this is just a test. I wouldnt really set password in a cookie if this wasn't just for fun. Do you know whats the problem?

Comment: Looks like a bug in reading username & password from cookie

Comment: is there the target cookies present?

Comment: I know I run the same method. Its not the cleanest code, but the functions both work.

Comment: have a look at the [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin

Comment: And yes there is target cookies present.

Comment: Can you show the value of `document.cookie` so that it can be seen to be in the correct format?

Comment: I dont want to use a plugin as other people might not have it.

Comment: use breakpoints or `console.log("message " + value);` to help you.

Comment: can you log the values in the client side

Comment: if the cookie is present then the methods seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aM278/1/ - add the following logging statements to the `auth` method `console.log(document.cookie); console.log(messageType, userName, password)`

Comment: Looks like the JS works perfectly in FIREFOX, but in IE the cookies cant get called. 

I need to get it to work in IE. Does anyone know why it might not work in IE?

Comment: Basically undefined in IE, but defined in Firefox.

Comment: Its very frustrating. HTTPS certificates is doesnt work in Firefox so Im forced to use IE

Comment: Arun's fiddle works for me in IE. have you tried reducing your privacy settings for your IE browser to accept third party cookies?

Comment: Seems IE is less forgiving than FIrefox with some things in JS.... I have found the problem and will close this.